# Split 5-sided regular polygon on triangles

Tags: geometry, polygons

Recently in my geometry class I was asked to solve the following geometry problem:

*Split five-sided regular polygon on triangles s.t. every triangle has common segment with exactly three other triangles.*

I've wasted too much time on it and still don't understand how to even start solving this.

I found this split for 4-sided polygon

[image]

As you can see it is the right split, e.g. every triangle in it has exactly three neighbors.

Do you have any idea, how to solve this?

Comment: Simply extend your construction for the square to the pentagon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work for any convex $n$-gon:

[image]